# How to show description of code(s) from a single delimited field with multiple values?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

We have a questionnaire that has a multiple select area and the way it was built is that it stores the values in code form separated by semicolons:

(Example:ROADS;RECREAT;PRKSTRLS;FLEET;)

Is there a way in Crystal Reports to make it so when it displays this field it shows the description values instead of the codes??

I know I can make a formula like:

if {GTASSETMGMT.PLAN_SCOPE_CATEGORY} = "ROADS;RECREAT;PRKSTRLS;FLEET;" then 'Roads and Bridges, Recreation (e.g. Pools, Arenas, etc.), Parks and Trails, Fleet'

with the but since the could be 100's of possible combinations of the how the codes could be selected and stored I don't think that the way to try and achieve this.

So what I am looking for is a way to say regardless of which order they are stored it shows the description not the codes.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing your data in such a way, this is a significant sql-anti-pattern / code-smell.  Each item of data should be *a single item of data*.  Instead you should have multiple rows; one for Roads, one for Recreate, etc, in a structure that has a many:many relationship with some dimension table(s).  *(Such as each question having 0..many answers, each represented by its own row of data.)*

Comment: I agree with what you saying but I was not part of the development of the table and now I have to find a way to work with the data that is already stored in the table.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  You're likely going to need the normalised structure in order to do your join.  That's likely to be a table-value-function to create the right number of rows with the appropriate single value in each row.  The exact nature of that, however, depends largely on whether you're using MySQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, TeraData, etc, etc.  Then, once you have done this, are you going to try to compress the results back into a new string list?

Comment: Well I had hoped there might be a way to tell Crystal Reports what each code value is and let it display the results accordingly without having to change the table in the database.

Comment: Can you create new views in database? If yes, then you can create view, linking your multivalue fields to description table (using like operator and some string manipulation). In Crystal Reports itself it can be done too (by not linking descriptions table and seelecting records in record selection formula), but this is higly inefficient and may not always work either.

Comment: @TaunBrown - Unfortunately the reason the functionality you wish to have is unavailable is that the design pattern chosen is a sql-anti-pattern; My car doesn't support the ability to run on both petrol and diesel, instead it requires me just to use diesel.  As you are forced to live with this unfortunately designed database, you now have to jump through hoops as a consequence.  *(The correct fix being to change the structure in the database.)*  If you tell us which RDBMS you are using, we may be able to show you which hoops are available to you for jumping through...

Comment: would you be able to give me an example of what that view might look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use some simple string manipulation to get what you want if you're stuck with that database design. It boils down to splitting the string at the ;-delimiter and translating each code to its description piece-by-piece. Something like this:

```
local stringvar sample := "ROADS;RECREAT;PRKSTRLS;FLEET;";
local stringvar array a := split(sample, ';');
local stringvar out := "";
local numbervar i;

for i := 1 to count(a)-1 do //assume sample terminates in semicolon
 out := out +
  (select a[i]
   case "ROADS" : "Roads and Bridges"
   case "RECREAT" : "Recreation (e.g. Pools, Arenas, etc.)"
   case "PRKSTRLS" : "Parks and Trails"
   case "FLEET" : "Fleet"
   default : "") + ";";

out
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses I have to admit that what your describing is a bit beyond me right now. where would this code go?

Comment: @TaunBrown A formula.

Comment: so would I have to edit this formula so that he sample in the first line has every code in it and the case has each description for each value or do I need a formula like this for each possible combination of the data?

Comment: @TaunBrown The 'sample' variable is just a placeholder for your string value from the database, `{GTASSETMGMT.PLAN_SCOPE_CATEGORY}`. You only need this one formula, but, obviously, if there are more individual codes in the database than what are listed in your question then you will have to add more cases.

Comment: Got this but does seem to work:local stringvar sample := {GTASSETMGMT.PLAN_SCOPE_CATEGORY};
local stringvar array a := split(sample, ';');
local stringvar out := "";
local numbervar i;

for i := 1 to count(a)-1 do //assume sample terminates in semicolon
 out := out +
  (select a[i]
   case "CULTURAL" : "Cultural Infastructure (e.g. Libraries, Museums)"
   case "ROADS" : "Roads and Bridges"
   case "RECREAT" : "Recreation (e.g. Pools, Arenas, etc.)"
   case "PRKSTRLS" : "Parks and Trails"
   case "FLEET" : "Fleet"
   case "HOUSEING" : "Social Housing"
   default : "") + ";";

out

Comment: @TaunBrown Looks good to me. If this answer solves your problem then don't forget to accept it as the solution.

Comment: hopefully last question so that did work but I have 3 fields that I would need to do this for but when I add the second formula now it only show true or false as the values ... any idea why?

Comment: @TaunBrown You'd have to describe the problem and show the modified formula, but that's a question for another thread.

Comment: Thanks Ryan I will do that once the site lets people post questions again. the code I used for the second formula that for some reason only shows true or false will post below for now.

Comment: local stringvar sample := "PUBMEET;POLLING;";
local stringvar array a := split(sample, ';');
local stringvar out := "";
local numbervar j;

for j := 1 to count(a)-1 do //assume sample terminates in semicolon
 out := out +
  (select a[j]
   case "PUBMEET" : "Public Meetings"
   case "POOLING" : "Surveys/Polling"
   case "DIRECT" : "Direct Marketing (letters, flyers, pamphlets, etc.)"
   case "SMEDIA" : "Use of new media (internet, blogs, social media, etc.)"
   case "TMEDIA" : "Use of traditional media (newspaper, TV, radio, etc.)"
   case "OTHER" : "Other"
   default : "") + ";";

Comment: Found the issue myself thanks again for all your help